Why Microsoft store still displays a greyed out button with "Installed" for my app after I publish new version app?
My app installer is msi format.
My app(installer) ver.1 was existed on Microsoft Store, users can download and install it.
However after I publish ver.2 app(installer), the users who installed my app can only see a greyed out button with "Installed" text. User has to uninstall my app manually and then can download ver.2 app.
What should I do then Microsoft store can detect that my app is able to update?
Thanks~
I have tried to config my installer to Major update and Minor update but both not work.
